# script performance in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I'd like to create a game in html5 with canvas.

But I have a performance question before

Is it better to create a variable each time I need one

```
var game = ...
var car = ...
var monster = ...
```

or is it better to instantiate only one `var` at the beginning of the script and do:

```
var game = {}
game.car = ...
game.monster = {}
game.monster.attack = function(){...}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you protect the variables from global scope. I wouldn't worry about this, it's trivial micro-optimization.

Comment: 1) http://jsperf.com 2) optimise for correctness, then for speed

Comment: If there is a difference, you probably won't notice it.

Comment: In my opinion, you better use libraries like Base.js and Event.js and other closure-libs. It will allow you to implement MVP/MVVM patterns in your js-code, so it will be more flexible and readable. It will also look like class-based inheritance.

Comment: Prototype inheritence is very powerful, when it is understood. I don't understand the movement to try to force classical inheretence into JavaScript.  We have plenty of languages, some excellent, for classical inheretence.   The prototype model has its own strengths, which are part of the strength of JavaScript.  Prototype inheritance isn't  one of its "bad parts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the comments you will not really need to wonder about this too much. The biggest thing that comes with doing javascript game programming is that you will have different computer that will have different hardware. Therefore framerates will be different for all of them if you dont interpolate you engine. An example of this would be

```
// Updated drawing code for our objects
Rect.prototype.draw = function(context, interpolation) {
  context.fillRect(this.x, this.y + this.velocity * interpolation, 30, 30);
};

Game.draw = function(interpolation) {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);

  for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {
    this.entities[i].draw(this.context, interpolation);
  }
};

Game.run = (function() {
  var loops = 0, skipTicks = 1000 / Game.fps,
      maxFrameSkip = 10,
      nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime(),
      lastGameTick;

  return function() {
    loops = 0;

    while ((new Date).getTime() > nextGameTick) {
      Game.update();
      nextGameTick += skipTicks;
      loops++;
    }

    if (!loops) {
      Game.draw((nextGameTick - (new Date).getTime()) / skipTicks);
    } else {
      Game.draw(0);
    }
  };
})();
```

This will keep the game logic at your Game.fps. Another thing that you maybe want to avoid is using jQuery in your drawing logic. This is due to the fact that jQuery's animation queue is very slow and you end up having animations stack to the infinite giving you a larger delay with every frame.

Answer (score 2):

The difference should be so small that you can ignore it. Usually you can rely on the interpreter to perform any such micro-optimizations for you in the background. What you need to focus on are your algorithms.

A rule of thumb in game development is: *The performance bottleneck is always the graphic engine*. That's where you have to optimize. Avoid over-drawing, avoid re-drawing, avoid drawing invincible stuff, cache, cache, cache.

Answer (score 2):

This test (http://jsperf.com/to-scope-or-not-to-scope) shows that using the local scope is by far the fastest way to go, but creating a self-invoking function just to *have* a scope more than offsets it.

The best you can do is just use whatever scope you have at hand. The worst you can do (except for the usage of the `with` keyword) performance-wise is to use a self-invoking function within a tight loop (you should still do it if you want to close over the iteration variable i.e. create a new function anyways). Anything else is sligthly slower than just using the local scope.

Note that javascript does *not* use block scoping - any `var`iable is scoped to its enclosing function.

Also note that you should minimise the amount of graphics operations, not the overhead from your code around them.

Also note that you should make sure the program will be maintainable, then care about performance.